# Scrapy: Attempts to extract data from selector list not right

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape football fixtures from a website and my spider is not quite right as I either get the same fixture repeated for all selectors or `homeTeam` and `awayTeam`variables are huge arrays that contain all home sides or away sides respectively. Either way it should reflect the Home vs Away format.

This is my current attempt:

```
class FixtureSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "fixturesSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.bbc.co.uk"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="table-stats"]/tbody/tr[@class="preview"]'):

        item = Fixture()
        item['kickoff'] =  str(sel.xpath("//table[@class='table-stats']/tbody/tr[@class='preview']/td[3]/text()").extract()[0].strip())
        item['homeTeam'] = str(sel.xpath("//table[@class='table-stats']/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/span/a/text()").extract()[0].strip())
        item['awayTeam'] = str(sel.xpath("//table[@class='table-stats']/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/span/a/text()").extract()[1].strip())
        yield item
```

This returns the below information repeatedly which is incorrect:

```
2015-03-20 21:41:40+0000 [fixturesSpider] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures>
{'awayTeam': 'West Brom', 'homeTeam': 'Man City', 'kickoff': '12:45'}
2015-03-20 21:41:40+0000 [fixturesSpider] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures>
{'awayTeam': 'West Brom', 'homeTeam': 'Man City', 'kickoff': '12:45'}
```

Could someone let me know where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the XPath expressions you are using in the loop are absolute - they start from the root element, but should be relative to a current row which `sel` is pointing to. In other words, you need to search *in the current row context*.

Fixed version:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="table-stats"]/tbody/tr[@class="preview"]'):
    item = Fixture()
    item['kickoff'] =  str(sel.xpath("td[3]/text()").extract()[0].strip())
    item['homeTeam'] = str(sel.xpath("td[2]/p/span/a/text()").extract()[0].strip())
    item['awayTeam'] = str(sel.xpath("td[2]/p/span/a/text()").extract()[1].strip())
    yield item
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
{'awayTeam': 'West Brom', 'homeTeam': 'Man City', 'kickoff': '12:45'}
{'awayTeam': 'Swansea', 'homeTeam': 'Aston Villa', 'kickoff': '15:00'}
{'awayTeam': 'Arsenal', 'homeTeam': 'Newcastle', 'kickoff': '15:00'}
...
```

---

If you want to grab the match dates, you need to change the strategy - iterate over dates (`h2` elements with `table-header` class) and get the first following sibling `table` element:

```
for date in response.xpath('//h2[@class="table-header"]'):
    matches = date.xpath('.//following-sibling::table[@class="table-stats"][1]/tbody/tr[@class="preview"]')
    date = date.xpath('text()').extract()[0].strip()

    for match in matches:
        item = Fixture()
        item['date'] = date
        item['kickoff'] = match.xpath("td[3]/text()").extract()[0].strip()
        item['homeTeam'] = match.xpath("td[2]/p/span/a/text()").extract()[0].strip()
        item['awayTeam'] = match.xpath("td[2]/p/span/a/text()").extract()[1].strip()
        yield item
```

Comment: Hi @alecxe that worked perfect. Thank you. 

Now im trying to get the date associated for that match. Which means from the relative position i have to navigate back up till i reach the h2[@class='table-header']

Trying to follow your strategy by grabbing the match date using a relative xpath  str(sel.xpath("td/../../../../h2/text()").extract()) for one game its grabs all the dates into an array.

I realised that my xpath is returning all the fixtures date from this page instead of just the first one it finds

Comment: Instead of iterating over the fixtures and getting the parent date, would it be easier/sensible to iterate over the h2 dates, getting the matches for each?

Comment: Thanks @alecxe but your new strategy seems to be pulling only the fixtures for the final fixtures date.

Comment: Actually its fine @alecxe there were indentation issues. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the selectors below.  I believe you need `...tbody//tr/...` instead of `...tbody/tr/...` to get all table rows instead of just the first one.

```
    item['kickoff'] =  str(sel.xpath("//table[@class='table-stats']/tbody//tr[@class='preview']/td[3]/text()").extract()[0].strip())
    item['homeTeam'] = str(sel.xpath("//table[@class='table-stats']/tbody//tr/td[2]/p/span/a/text()").extract()[0].strip())
    item['awayTeam'] = str(sel.xpath("//table[@class='table-stats']/tbody//tr/td[2]/p/span/a/text()").extract()[1].strip())
```

Comment: Hi @chishaku I tried that. I still got same result.